# Mostrar Item seleccionado de un spinner dinamico con un Toast en android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Tengo un text edit y un botón que agregan valores a un adapter y se muestra en un listView y un spinner, quiero mostrar en un mensaje el elemento seleccionado, aquí mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText txt;
    Button save;
    Spinner opcion;

    ArrayList<String> addArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInput);
        opcion =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spOpcion);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, addArray);
        opcion.setAdapter(adapter);
        opcion.setPrompt("Selecciona una opción");

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String getInput = txt.getText().toString();

                if(addArray.contains(getInput))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "El Elemento ya se había agregado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(getInput.trim().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Elemento vacío, ingrese texto antes de guardar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if(!addArray.contains(getInput))
                {
                    addArray.add(getInput);
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput)).setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        opcion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView)
            {
                //Nada seleccionado
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Aquí están los elementos cargados en el spinner, pero al seleccionar uno, no se muestra el mensaje]

[image: Mensaje de elemento repetido]

Comment: A ver si entendi, quieres mostrar el texto del elemento seleccionado del Spinner?

Comment: Sí, la mayoría de ejemplos tienen un arreglo estático o en el xml le agregan valores, pero no tengo idea de como mandar llamar itemSelected del spinner opcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el método `onItemSelected` obtienes la posición (`position`) en `int` 
y obtienes el `string` que hay en esa posicion con `getSelectedItem().toString()`:

```
opcion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "El Elemento seleccionado es posición número: "+position +" El String es: "+opcion.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: si agrego este código, me aparece el mensaje cuando le doy click al botón que guarda el text edit , y si selecciono el elemento en spinner, no ocurre nada, el contexto que se le asigna es del botón, pero no sé como darle el contexto del spinner

Comment: quieres ver el toast al seleccionar en el spinner?

Comment: Si, es que esa selección la pienso usar después además de mostrarle al usuario la opción que seleccionó

Comment: Tuve que añadir una opción como hint en el arreglo y con eso se activaron los eventos de la selección del spinner

Answer (score 1):

después `opcion.setSelection(0);` agregar este código:

```
opcion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
         //Nada seleccionado
        }

    });
```

Comment: No se ve el evento, se guarda lo del edit text, pero al elegir un elemento del spinner no aparece el Toast

Comment: Es porque "addArray" está vacío. por ejemplo agregar este codigo antes opcion.setOnItemSelectedListener : addArray.add("Hola Android");

Comment: se supone que el spinner se alimenta del adapter de addArray cada vez que agrego un elemento con text edit y le doy al botón guardar, abro el spinner y se ven los elementos, pero al elegir uno, no pasa nada